# Style the element in <HeaderTemplate> of Datalist

Tags: css, asp.net, datalist

I am designing an `ASP.NET` page with using some data from `SQL Server Database`. I used `<DataList>` to call data and fill any place I want to in the page. My problem is, CSS seems not working for the element in `<HeaderTemplate>`. I searched some posts but I couldn't find an answer.

I tried to style `<p>` like you see in the code, and I tried to style the data I called with `<span>` too. Then I tried to use both of them at the same time as you see. None of them works.

**Here is my code:**

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
         <img class="img-circle"   src="../Images/icons/1.png" alt="Generic placeholder image" height="120" width="120" style="position:relative;">
         <h2>Last News</h2>
         <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
             <HeaderTemplate><p style="text-align:center;"></HeaderTemplate>
             <ItemTemplate><span style="text-align:center;"><%#Eval("news_header") %></span></ItemTemplate>
             <FooterTemplate></p></FooterTemplate>
         </asp:DataList>       
         <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="haberler.aspx" role="button">Devamını Oku »</a></p>
</div>
```

**UPDATE and SOLUTION:**

When I looked at the codes in browser while localhos was working, I saw the problem was `table` that Datalist creates. So I framed that `table` with `div` just out of `Datalist`code and write the CSS class to make it work with all screen sizes. Here is the codes:

Asp.Net Side:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
     <img class="img-circle"   src="../Images/icons/1.png" alt="Generic placeholder image" height="120" width="120" style="position:relative;">
     <h2>Son Haberler</h2>
       <div class="col-lg-12"><asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
           <HeaderStyle  CssClass="deneme2"/>
             <ItemTemplate>
                <span><%#Eval("haber_baslik_tr") %></span>
             </ItemTemplate> 
           </asp:DataList></div>    
     <br /><p><a class="btn btn-default" href="haberler.aspx" role="button">Devamını Oku »</a></p>
  </div>
```

CSS Side:

```
.col-lg-12 table{
        width:100%;
    }
.col-lg-12 table tbody tr td{
     text-align:center;
    }
```

Comment: can you please provide sample html of output you want because i think you need ItemTemplate only <ItemTemplate><p><span style="text-align:center;"><%#Eval("news_header") %></p></ItemTemplate>

Comment: I tried your advice too. It looks okay in the big screen right now as i tried before, but when I make the browser smaller, it seems the part where ItemTemplate stay where it is. It doesnt work on mobile screen in short. I cant give you html sample because it is an aspx page. I dont want to lose time to write html. I can give you screenshot to see what it the problem with design. Here is the ss: http://tinypic.com/r/2u7lg0w/8

Comment: then you are not using bootstrap classes properly.  try following          <HeaderTemplate><ul class="list-group"></HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate><li class="list-group-item"><%#Eval("news_header") %></li></ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>

Comment: Nope it is not working either. When I look at the codes in browser while it works on localhost, I saw datalist creating a table. Now I am trying to frame that Datalist table with div so I can manipulate it. Let's see what happens. I will update when I find a solution. Thank you for your advice ^^

Comment: Yep, adding `<div> `with right Css rules does wonders! :) I will update my question to post the solution

Answer (score 0):

Use **[DataList.HeaderStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.headerstyle(v=vs.110).aspx)**

```
<HeaderStyle CssClass="MyHeaderClass">
 </HeaderStyle>
```

Comment: Hmm I tried the do opposite I guess. I tried to use itemsyle instead of that. Let me try yours and i will be back! Thank you for your advice :)

Comment: see the link first, you'll understand everything.

Comment: nope, it doesnt seem working either. I also try to forget `<headertemplate>` and tried to write `<ItemTemplate>
                     <p style="text-align: center;"><%#Eval("haber_baslik_tr") %></p>
                 </ItemTemplate>` It does make the text align center but not working with other css groups. Here is the pic http://tinypic.com/r/f0vh2q/8 I want it to look like the right one exactly. :/

Comment: In the end, I forgo `HeaderTemplate` and I used `p` in `ItemTemplate` and just added margin-left to style `p`. At least it looks right, right now :)